# What timezone is cron in?

Tags: cron

If I run `crontab -e` and add a cronjob `4 5 * * * "echo hi"`, the job will run at 5:04 of what timezone? Let's say the laptop displays time in PST in the top menu bar and `sudo systemsetup -gettimezone` is `Time Zone: America/Los_Angeles`.

I tried running a test job to find the answer, but the job didn't run when I expected in both UTC and PST. Probably a simple misconfiguration, but I'd like to confirm what timezone I should expect first.

Comment: @Allan I ran the `mail` command later and found out that the syntax was misconfigured, as I thought. If you go into a mail it says the time and timezone, which matches the system time. So feel free to post that as the answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cron` will run at it’s scheduled time based on the system time regardless of timezone.  For instance, your scheduled  job will run at 5:04am system time. If you’re in LA at 2am and you head to Miami where the time adjusts to 5am local (assuming you got a ride with The Flash), your job will run at 5:04am (Miami time).

The job, however, will not run if the computer is asleep; it will just run at it’s next scheduled event time. I also suggest looking at utilizing [`launchd`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/249446/119271) as `cron` was supposedly deprecated by Apple in it’s favor.

Comment: Relevant: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25896/what-is-the-difference-between-cron-and-launchd